# Unable to check the dataflow output activity metrics - ADF

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory

I am trying to check if the dataflow has written any rows to the sink and capture the activity output. the update statement fails, if the activity doesn't write any rows to the sink , so as per MS docs I am trying the below expression in a lookup activity.

```
***DECLARE @Date DATETIME;

SET @Date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @ROWSAFFECT INT;

SET @ROWSAFFECT =  if(contains(@{activity('dataflow').output.runStatus}, 'sink'), '@{activity('dataflow').output.runStatus.metrics.sink.rowsWritten}','0');

update table [schema].[audit_table] 
SET LOAD_STATUS ='Success' 
,ROWS_AFFECTED = @ROWSAFFECT

select 1;***
```

But this fails with a parse error. Can someone please help me with this?

***=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Parse error at line: 4, column: 217: Incorrect syntax near ']'.'***

Comment: Can you please provide additional information regarding the pipeline? And is the dataflow activity running without any issue (when run using debug)?

Comment: Yes, the dataflow is completing fine. I am trying to get this output metric into a lookup activity and use it in an update statement. If I try the expression without the 'If' statement to get the rowswritten, it works fine when the acitivity had written some rows. But that fails when there are no rows written to sink. So I want to include the check.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide full query written in the pipeline expression builder.

Comment: updated the question. Can you pelase take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query written with dynamic content to assign the value for `@ROWAFFECT` is incorrect.

- The main issue is with the `@contains()` inside the `if`. You should be searching for 'sink' in `contains(activity('dataflow').output.runStatus.metrics`.
- I have tried the following query to insert into my azure SQL database table (dbo.audit) for demonstration.

```
DECLARE @ROWSAFFECT INT;

SET @ROWSAFFECT = @{if(contains(activity('dataflow').output.runStatus.metrics, 'sink'), activity('dataflow').output.runStatus.metrics.sink.rowsWritten,0)};

update [dbo].[audit] SET LOAD_STATUS ='Success' ,ROWS_AFFECTED = @ROWSAFFECT
```

[image]

The following is the debug query that is being run for each case.

- When rowsWritten is 0:

[image]

- When there are n=10 records:

[image]